# Scala: can not print list elements

Tags: list, scala, printing

I did "mkString" but still can not print list of strings. With input line:

```
9002194187,2644,54,100,3,4,2,5
```

I get the following output:

```
Line: 9002194187,2644,54,100,3,4,2,5
StrArr: 9002194187,2644,54,100,3,4,2,5
Lst: [Ljava.lang.String;@223d2e6c
Lst again: List([Ljava.lang.String;@223d2e6c)
Lst1: [Ljava.lang.String;@223d2e6c
Result: foo
```

From the code below:

```
def mkRecord(line: String) : String = {
    val klass = "foo"
    val strArr = line.split(",") // convert string to array of strings
    println("Line: "+line)
    println("StrArr: "+strArr.mkString(","))
    val lst = List(strArr)
    println("Lst: "+lst.mkString(" - "))
    println("Lst again: "+lst)
    val lst1 = lst.tail ++ List(klass) // attribute list except for the first one, plus new klass attribute
    println("Lst1: "+lst.mkString(" , "))
    val result = lst1.mkString(",") // attribute string
    println("Result: "+ result)
    return result
  }
```

Please, help. I am at complete loss (

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor for List (actually, the apply method on the List companion object) takes parameters in the form of scala's "varargs" equivalent:

```
def apply[A](xs: A*): List[A] // some irrelevant details have been elided
```

In java, this would be written something like:

```
public static List<A> apply(A... args)
```

In scala this *can* be called using any Seq (or subclass), but using a special notation. The line you used:

```
val lst = List(strArr)
```

creates a `List[Array[String]]`, with a single entry - the array strArr. To tell the compiler to turn the array into a varargs when passing it to the List `apply` method, add `: _*` on the end (the space is optional):

```
val lst = List(strArr: _*)
```

This change in your code will result in:

```
scala> mkRecord(chkStr)
Line: 9002194187,2644,54,100,3,4,2,5
StrArr: 9002194187,2644,54,100,3,4,2,5
Lst: 9002194187 - 2644 - 54 - 100 - 3 - 4 - 2 - 5
Lst again: List(9002194187, 2644, 54, 100, 3, 4, 2, 5)
Lst1: 9002194187 , 2644 , 54 , 100 , 3 , 4 , 2 , 5
Result: 2644,54,100,3,4,2,5,foo
res1: String = 2644,54,100,3,4,2,5,foo
```

Comment: Where to read about  ": _*" Scala operator? Many thanks for detailed info!

Comment: Search for terms like "scala varargs", you should hit pages such as [this one](http://daily-scala.blogspot.com.au/2009/11/varargs.html)

Comment: @AntonAshanin in Shadowlands' example, the underscore is providing a type ascription, something which is not well documented in most pages describing the various uses of the underscore.

  http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/types.html

Answer (score 0):

You can turn any array into a list with its `toList` operator, avoiding this problem (the nature of which Shadowlands has explained).  You can do string -> array -> list in one line:

```
line.split(',').toList
```

Using a collection's `toList` method is often going to be faster than extracting all the elements into a sequence and then converting that sequence into a list, not least because you'll be using a method optimised for the source collection.  However, that's an optimisation which you can worry about *after* the priorities of success and clarity.

Comment: It's worth noting that as of Scala 2.10, .toList and all of the many, many similar collection transformation functions have their functionalities merged into ".to".  Your example could be written line.split(',').to[List]